# Delete old rows in change log for Firestore to BigQuery Extenstion

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, firebase-extensions

I am using the Firebase Extension Stream Firestore to BigQuery to export my data to BQ.
It is working great, and I have been using it for a couple of years now.
However, the table size is starting to get larger causing an increase in cost for my queries.
I have the following tables created by this and npx @firebaseextensions/fs-bq-schema-views:

- mytable_raw_changelog (1,327,594 rows)
- mytable_raw_latest (55,329 rows)
- mytable_schema_changelog (1,332,454 rows)
- mytable_schema_latest (55,745 rows, 3.2GB query)

A single SELECT from the mytable_schema_latest table now processes 3.2GB

The options I can think of are

1. Remove old rows from the _changelog that are no longer needed
2. Add time partitioning using the Firebase BQ extension config
3. Create a job to copy the mytable_schema_latest to another table for querying (without the historic changes)

**I am looking to go with Option 1 - remove old rows for now as this seems the simplest.
Is there a recommended way or any guides on how to do this?**

I only want to remove old historic changes that occurred before a certain date where the document has since been updated.

It may also be a good idea to copy these to a historic table before deleting them in case I need them in the future.

**Update 204-03-28:**
I noticed there is a new parameter with the latest version of the extension. Not much info but maybe this will do the trick?

> Exclude old data payloads If enabled, table rows will never contain
> old data (document snapshot before the update), which should be more
> performant, and avoid potential resource limitations.

Answer (score 1):

To create a "backup" of a given table, you can simply run a query and then use ***SAVE RESULTS >> BigQuery Table*** to save to a new table.  Now you have a "backup" and if something goes wrong you can restore from this new table.

I think the following SQL statement might delete "old" rows for you:

```sql
DELETE FROM your_dataset.your_table
  WHERE STRUCT(document_id, timestamp) NOT IN (
      SELECT AS STRUCT document_id, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
      FROM your_dataset.your_table
      GROUP BY document_id
  )
```